# Setting PATH on OS X 10.9 is not working

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew

I have searched all posts regarding PATH issues on Mac, but have not found an answer to mine.

I want to get `/usr/local/bin` to be searched first. I used homebrews example but it did not work. I created the `.bash_profile` file and put in:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

As homebrew says except this seems to remove the standard commands for me with `ls`, `cd`, etc not working. I want it to search this folder first. I found the `/etc/paths` file and saw that it `/usr/local/bin` is located last.

Following instructions found here not to mess with the path file, I removed the change I made to `.bash_profile` and was able to get it to work (`brew doctor` is successful) with putting in

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I have tested this on two different Macs, and neither accepts appending the `$PATH`. Doing some research it seems that there is a path_helper file which calls stuff which may have changed in OS x 10.9. Is there a way to get the appending to work? I have tried it with the quotes and without and neither works. And each time I have restarted terminal or tried the source `~/.bash_profile` command

I would prefer to not rewrite the whole path in .bash_profile, or at least know why appending it is not working.

Comment: what happens when you simple type `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` in your terminal instead of putting it in a .bash file?

Comment: Are you sure you're using _double_ quotes around the variable value? What does `echo $SHELL` return on the command line?

Comment: When typing export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" into the Termminal it worked properly. I ran $PATH and it reported /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

Comment: echo $SHELL gave me /bin/bash and yes I am doing double quotes. I have also tried single quotes but that did not work either.

Comment: Are they _regular_ double quotes or _typographical_ ones? The latter wouldn't work. (It is expected that _single_ quotes do _not_ work). What does `echo $PATH` report after reading `~/.bash_profile`? If you want me to notified of your response, add "@mklement0" to it.

Comment: @mklement0 They are regular double quotes. And rebooting Terminal and running echo $PATH after loading the path in .bash_profile gave me "/usr/local/bin:??

Comment: Are the `??` part of the output? Could there be an encoding issue with respect to your `~/.bash_profile` file? Make sure it is a UTF8-encoded file. What does `locale` report?

Comment: @mklement0 yes it is part of the output. The ?? follow the colon. I created the .bash_profile using touch /.bash_profile and TextEdit is showing UTF8 encoding.

Comment: `?` usually indicates a byte [sequence] that Terminal.app can't render, because it is invalid for the active char. encoding. There are 2 factors at play: (1) the encoding as reported by `locale` and (2) Terminal.app's encoding as specified via Preferences > Settings > (profile name) > Advanced > Character encoding:`

Comment: @mklement0 locale is showing en_US.UTF-8 for all except LC_all. And under Prefersences > Settings > (Unicode) UTF-8

Comment: If `echo $PATH` _without_ modification in `~/.bash_profile` shows the normal `$PATH` value, the problem must be with your `~/.bash_profile` file.

Comment: @mklement0 I deleted the .bash_profile and then created it again. Same issue. I think the issue lies with the Terminal not being able to read $PATH. When I manually type in my path without using $PATH it works properly.

Comment: You mentioned `TextEdit`, which is generally NOT a good choice for plain-text editor (consider something like Sublime Text). Make sure you haven't accidentally created `~/.bash_profile` as an _RTF_ (rich-text) file - it MUST be a _plain-text_ file (`Format > Make Plain Text`).

Comment: As far as I could tell, I created in Text Edit properly. Redoing it with Sublime Text worked though. Thanks a lot @mklement0 by the way, any chance you know how to have PATH not go through /usr/local/bin twice? I only want it once in the beginning.

Comment: Glad to hear it; I've summed up our exchange in a new answer, where I've also answered your follow-up question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation it turns out that the **problem may have been how file `~/.bash_profile`** was created - **it may not have been a *plain-text* file** (due to use of TextEdit).

Recreating it with a plain-text editor (Sublime Text) solved the problem.

---

Follow-up question by the OP:

As for prepending `/usr/local/bin` without having it appear *twice* in `$PATH`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH/:\/usr\/local\/bin/}"
```

`${PATH/:\/usr\/local\/bin/}`, using bash's parameter/variable expansion, removes `/usr/local/bin`, if present, from the existing `$PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem after installing homebrew.

In the end, it came down to the fact that `brew doctor` was suggesting I modify ~/.bash_profile when all my usual (old) settiings were in ~/.profile. If you read the bash manpage though it tells you that bash first reads /etc/profile and then `THE FIRST ONE OF` ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile - not all of them!

What I am saying is to agglomerate all your setttings in ONE of thos e files only.

Comment: Is this a separate .profile than the one in /etc/profile? Because I have no .profile in my home directory

Comment: It is separate and specific to you whereas /etc/profile is used for all users.

Comment: As a general rule, you can use both `~/.profile` (for POSIX-compatible code) and `~/.bash_profile` (for `bash`-specific code) by adding `. ~/.profile` to the beginning of `~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 1):

edit the `/etc/paths` to look like

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

if it didn't work then add `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` to the `.bash_profile` and it should work...